# how to get joint pdf of mixed random variables

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function, joint-distribution, inverse-gamma-distribution

I would like to know how the joint probability density function $p(b,r,\sigma^2)$ can be calculated for the following graph. Random variable $b$ is a latent binary variable, and random variable $\sigma^2$ is Inverse-Gamma. Random variable $r$ is observed and assumed Gaussian with two means ($\mu_0 = -1$ and $\mu_1 = 1$). In other words, $r$ can be generated from a Gaussian with mean = -1 or it can be generated from a Gaussian with mean 1.

$\sigma^2$ represents a common variance between the two Gaussians.

[image: Bayes network]

Comment: What happens when you try to factorize this graph?

Comment: So my understanding of probability density function is that in 1-D single variable $p(r)dr$ is the probability of sampling between $r$ and $r+dr$ where $r$ is a continuous variable
as a binary variable, $b$ can equal 0 with probability $\pi$ and 1 with probability $1-\pi$
seems to me that $p(r,b,\sigma^2) = \left(\pi\delta_{\beta,0}+(1-\pi)\delta_{\beta,1}\right)p(r,\sigma^2)$

Answer (score 1):

This graph can be factorized according to the usual rules of Bayesian graphs:

$$
p(b,r,\sigma^2) = p(r|b,\sigma^2)p(b)p(\sigma^2)
$$

If you want the marginal distribution $p(r, \sigma^2)$ (that is, averaged over possible $b$ outcomes), then you have the familiar mixture density:

$$
p(r,\sigma^2) = \Pr(b=1)p(r|b=1,\sigma^2)p(\sigma^2) + \Pr(b=0)p(r|b=0,\sigma^2)p(\sigma^2)
$$

I'm abusing notation pretty badly here. I can clarify if any of it doesn't make sense.

Comment: what will $p(r|b,\sigma^2)$ be, when the means $\mu_0 = -1$ and $\mu_1 = 1$ are known and the variance unknown?

Comment: @fountain3 you are conditioning on $\sigma^2$, so it must be known. Just write $\sigma^2$. For $\mu$, you can write $\mu_b$, since $b$ is also known.

Comment: Terribly sorry I meant to write $p(r,\sigma^2|b)$. If $r$ is Gaussian, $\sigma^2$ is Gamma, and $b$ is binary, I need to get the expression for $p(r,\sigma^2|b)$.

Comment: @fountain3 just plug in $\mu_b$?

Comment: If I use the Normal-Gamma equation from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-gamma_distribution  what should I use for the parameters of the Gamma part?

Comment: @fountain3 $\alpha$ and $\beta$, what else could it be?

Comment: Sure, but what values should they take if I do not know what they are? Should I use a prior?

Comment: @fountain3 either you specify them, or you put a prior on them and infer them.